# Visual Studio 2019 Professional LiveShare not allowing Unit Testing

Tags: tdd, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-liveshare

Our team works in C# and has recently updated to Visual Studio 2019 Professional. We are attempting to use Live Share for TDD.

While we can see one another typing, the remote user cannot build or run unit tests.

Am I missing a configuration?

**Edit 1**
I know this is an old post at this point. It seems that Microsoft sacrificed usability for security. The only thing that you can do with LiveShare is write code together. The person coding tests cannot be remote (AFAIK). Also, to do pair programming it will kind of work in a bad way (i.e. the navigator can make changes but the driver will not necessarily see them especially if they are in another file unless explicitly told where to look). When it is time for the driver and navigator to switch, it almost seems easier to push the code to a repo, terminate the live share session and have the new driver pull it and start a new live share session.

As far as mob programming, this really seems to fail to scale.